# Removing the querystring in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, query-string

After reading and processing a query-string value from the URL, for example

```
http://myurl.com/#/?foo=baa
```

I can change the URL to

```
http://myurl.com/#/?foo=
```

by using

```
$location.search('myQueryStringParameter', '');
```

How do I get rid of the query-string altogether (without explicit redirects or server side action and so on) so that only

```
http://myurl.com/#/
```

remains in the browser? It should be fairly simple, but I can't find any reference.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
$location.url($location.path())
```

See [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location) for more information.

Comment: but it reloads the page

Comment: This clears all querystring key/value-s. What if I just want to remove only one of them?

Comment: @saf don't forget to set `reloadOnSearch:false` in your route

Comment: It gives error - 'transition superseded' in the console.

Answer (score 46):

You were close, you needed to set null

```
$location.search('myQueryStringParameter', null);
```

From [ng.$location documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search)

> If search is a string, then paramValue will override only a single search parameter. If paramValue is an array, it will set the parameter as a comma-separated value. **If paramValue is null, the parameter will be deleted.**

Comment: This for some reason is deleting all my parameters. If I have name=Olly&position=forward and I call $location.search(position, null), everything gets deleted.

Comment: @Alessandro if you can create a test project that reproduces it log it as a bug. It has worked as documented for me for a long (in Angular land) time now.

Comment: @toxaq but it reloads the page

Comment: @saf that's true of any change to $location.search you need reloadOnSearch:false in your route (if using default routing).

Answer (score 9):

The easiest solution is to do the same as internaly in $location.url

```
$location.search('')
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$location.url('/');
```

See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) for more information.

Comment: This would redirect the user to the root path and that's NOT what the OP wanted.